# Queries with stopwords and searchMode=all return no results

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

if I have a document with this words in the content:

"dolor de cabeza" using the spanish analyzer, searching for "dolor de cabeza" returns the document ok. but using dolor de cabeza (without quotes) returns nothing.

Actually, every stop word in the search query will make it to return no documents when using queryType=Full and searchMode=All.

the problem with using the quote approach is that it will only match the exact sentence.

is there any workaround? I think this is a BUG.

Comment: Do you have different, language-specific analyzers set on fields you are searching over?

Answer (score 5):

Short version:

This happens when you issue a search query with **searchMode=All** against fields that use analyzers that process stopwords differently. Please make sure you scope your query only to fields analyzed with the same analyzer using the **searchFields** search request parameter. Alternatively, you can set the same **searchAnalyzer** on all your searchable fields that removes stopwords from your query in the same way. To learn more about custom analyzers and how to search *indexAnalyzer* and *searchAnalyzer* independently, go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search).

Long version:

Let’s take an index with two fields where one is analyzed with English Lucene analyzer, and the other with standard (default) analyzer.

```
{
  "fields":[
    {
      "name":"docId",
      "type":"Edm.String",
      "key":true,
      "searchable":false
    },
    {
      "name":"field1",
      "type":"Edm.String",
      "analyzer":"en.lucene"
    },
    {
      "name":"field2",
      "type":"Edm.String"
    }
  ]
}
```

Let’s add these two documents:

```
{
  "value":[
    {
      "docId":"1",
      "field1":"Waiting for a bus",
      "field2":"Exploring cosmos"
    },
    {
      "docId":"2",
      "field1":"Run to the hills",
      "field2":"run for your life"
    }
  ]
}
```

The following query doesn’t return any results *search=wait+for&searchMode=all*

It's because terms in this query are processed independently for each of the fields in the index by the analyzer defined for that field. 
For *field1* the query becomes *search=wait* (‘for’ was removed as it is a stop word) 
For *field2* it stays *search=wait+for* (the standard analyzer doesn’t remove stop words).

Only the first document matches ‘wait’ (in the first field), however the second field in the first document doesn’t match ‘for’, thus no results. When you set searchMode=all you tell the search engine that all query terms must be matched at least once.

For comparison, another query with a stopword *search=running+for&searchMode=all* returns the second document as a result. Term ‘running’ matches in *field1* (it’s stemmed) and ‘for’ matches in *field2*.

To learn more about query processing in Azure Search read [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture)

Comment: This is a but of a bummer. This means that searching in multiple languages using searchMode=All is useless. I understand the difficulties with multi-lingual search. But how to handle this properly? In our situation we have some english documents, and some french, and some dutch etc. And we have specific fields with language analyzers for each language. When searching, we don't know in what language the user is searching in. So we simply try to match the search query to any language. However, this causes this issue with stopwords