# Azure Search Fails to Return Expected Result When No OR Multiple SearchFields Are Defined

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I have a fairly basic Azure Search index with several fields of searchable string data, for example [abridged]...

```
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "Field1",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Field2",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "analyzer": "en.microsoft",
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
  }
]
```

`Field1` is loaded with alphanumeric id data and `Field2` is loaded with English language string data, specifically the name/title of the record. `searchMode=all` is also being used to ensure the accuracy of the results.

Let's say one of the records indexed has the following `Field2` data: `BA (Hons) in Business, Organisational Behaviour and Coaching`. Putting that into the `en.microsoft` analyzer, this is the result we get out:

```
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "ba",
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 2,
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "hon",
        "startOffset": 4,
        "endOffset": 8,
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "token": "hons",
        "startOffset": 4,
        "endOffset": 8,
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "token": "business",
        "startOffset": 13,
        "endOffset": 21,
        "position": 3
    },
    {
        "token": "organizational",
        "startOffset": 23,
        "endOffset": 37,
        "position": 4
    },
    {
        "token": "organisational",
        "startOffset": 23,
        "endOffset": 37,
        "position": 4
    },
    {
        "token": "behavior",
        "startOffset": 38,
        "endOffset": 47,
        "position": 5
    },
    {
        "token": "behaviour",
        "startOffset": 38,
        "endOffset": 47,
        "position": 5
    },
    {
        "token": "coach",
        "startOffset": 52,
        "endOffset": 60,
        "position": 7
    },
    {
        "token": "coaching",
        "startOffset": 52,
        "endOffset": 60,
        "position": 7
    }
]
```

As you can see, the tokens returned are what you'd expect for such a string. However, when it comes to using that same indexed string value as a search term (sadly a valid user case in this instance), the results returned are not as expected unless you explicitly use `searchFields=Field2`.

**Query 1 (Returns 0 results):**

```
?searchMode=all&search=BA%20(Hons)%20in%20Business%2C%20Organisational%20Behaviour%20and%20Coaching
```

**Query 2 (Returns 0 results):**

```
?searchMode=all&searchFields=Field1,Field2&search=BA%20(Hons)%20in%20Business%2C%20Organisational%20Behaviour%20and%20Coaching
```

**Query 3 (Returns 1 result as expected):**

```
?searchMode=all&searchFields=Field2&search=BA%20(Hons)%20in%20Business%2C%20Organisational%20Behaviour%20and%20Coaching
```

So why does this only return the expected result with `searchFields=Field2` and not with no `searchFields` defined or `searchFields=Field1,Field2`? I would not expect a no match on `Field1` to exclude a result that's clearly matching on `Field2`?

Furthermore, removing the `"in"` and `"and"` within the search term seems to correct the issue and return the expected result. For example:

**Query 4 (Returns 1 result as expected):**

```
?searchMode=all&search=BA%20(Hons)%20Business%2C%20Organisational%20Behaviour%20Coaching
```

(This is almost like one analyzer is tokenizing the indexed data and a completely different analyzer is tokenizing the search term, although that theory doesn't make any sense when taking into consideration Query 3, as that provides a positive match using the exact same indexed data/search term.)

Is anybody able to shed some light as to what's going on here as I'm completely out of ideas and I can't find anything more in the documentation?

NB. Please bear in mind that I'm looking to understand why Azure Search is behaving in this way and not necessarily wanting a work around.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't get any hits is due to how stopwords are handled when you use *searchMode=all*. The standard analyzer does not remove stopwords. The Lucene and Microsoft analyzers for English removes stopwords. I verified by creating an index with your property definitions and sample data. If you use the *standard* analyzer, stopwords are not removed and you will get a match also when using searchMode=all. To get a match when using either Lucene or Microsoft analyzers with simple query mode, you would have to use a phrase search.

When you test the en.microsoft analyzer in your example, you only get the response from what the first stage of the analyzer does. It splits your query into tokens. In your case, two of the tokens are also stopwords in English (in, and). Stopword removal is part of lexical analysis, which is done later in [stage 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture#stage-2-lexical-analysis) as explained in the article called [Anatomy of a search request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture). Furthermore, lexical analysis is only applied to "query types that require complete terms", like **searchMode=all**. See [Exceptions to lexical analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture#exceptions-to-lexical-analysis) for more examples.

There is a previous post here about this that explains in more detail. See [Queries with stopwords and searchMode=all return no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671272/queries-with-stopwords-and-searchmode-all-return-no-results)

I know you did not ask for workarounds, but to better understand what goes on it could be useful to list some possible workarounds.

- For English analyzers, use phrase search by wrapping the query in quotes: *search="BA (Hons) in Business, Organisational Behaviour and Coaching"&searchMode=all*
- The standard analyzer works the way you expect: *search=BA (Hons) in Business, Organisational Behaviour and Coaching&searchMode=all*
- Disable lexical analysis by [defining a custom analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers).