# Querytype=Full and searching for stop words returns no results

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

When using azure cognitive search, we are using full query syntax. When searching for something like: `the document` we create a query like this (this is a simplified example):

```
(Title:the OR Contents:the) AND (Title:document OR Contents:document)
```

(we need to split up the query for unrelated reasons)

The problem is that `the` **could** be a stopword in the language we are searching in (we search in several languages), causing the entire query to fail. We would like to be able to ignore stop words in generating queries like this, of have the search engine simply return true for the specific stop word search parts

I figure the latter is not possible. (or is it?). Might there be a way to query the stop words for specific language analyzers so we can exclude the stop words ourselves? Or is there a way to alter out query to be able to handle stop words better?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of another question that was posted at the same time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69974191/noise-stop-words-in-the-search-query-removes-correct-search-results

Comment: The option queryType=full does not seem relevant here. The full option only means that you can use the full Lucene syntax https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax instead of the simple syntax which is the default https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-simple-syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip stop words from your search query the only thing I can think of is calling the analyzer with the search query and check the returned tokens.
In this example you would call the en.microsoft analyzer with the search query "the document".
The tokens returned only contain "document", so you know "the" is considered a stop word by the analyzer. But when searching multiple languages you might need to call multiple analyzers and strip stop words for all those languages.